# PHP undefined function mysqli_connect

Tags: php, xampp

Editing since my question was closed for being similar to another question. I have tried those solutions and they did not work. Is there something else that could cause this problem?

I am getting "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Users\duke_\Projects\Project2\db_conn.php:9" when trying to connect to my mysql database. I am using xampp for the server and vs-code for the coding side of things. I am using PHP 8.2.8 on a windows 10 machine.
[Fatal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC9JI.png)

I read through some of the threads on here and tried the solutions suggested with making sure that extension=mysqli is enabled in php.ini [PHP.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzqrd.png)

however when i run "echo phpinfo();" it shows mysqlnd as enabled but no mention of mysqli.

I am very new to PHP and to coding in general. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask], including where it says about doing sufficient prior research, and not uploading your code etc as images. Thanks

Comment: PLease show the relevant code

Comment: Are you sure you changed the right copy of php.ini? Did you restart the webserver afterwards?

Comment: Please try to be more specific and list, which of the mentioned "those solutions" you tried without success, so we get a better overview of the state of your PHP installation